# Error with Quick Node Clone module - Non-reusable blocks must set an access dependency for access control

Tags: blocks, media, layout-builder

I am on Drupal version 10.1.6 and am using the [Quick Node Clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/quick_node_clone) module (v1.16). I can clone any nodes/pages and that all works fine. Most of my pages, if not all, are using layout builder where I can add my custom block types to each page. I have multiple custom block types that are Entity Reference with reference type of Media and a Media type of Image. For example, I have this hero banner block type that has a media field to add a background image to the block.

Now let's say I clone a page with a hero banner block and then want to change the image in the new cloned pag. When I open the layout builder, select to configure the block and remove the existing image and open the media library and select the new image, when I click the insert button, I get the following error:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 403 Debugging information follows. Path: /media-library?destination=/node/365/layout&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax&ajax_form=1&media_library_opener_id=media_library.opener.field_widget&media_library_allowed_types%5Bimage%5D=image&media_library_selected_type=image&media_library_remaining=1&media_library_opener_parameters%5Bfield_widget_id%5D=field_background_image_desktop%3A-settings-block_form&media_library_opener_parameters%5Bentity_type_id%5D=block_content&media_library_opener_parameters%5Bbundle%5D=full_width_image_cta&media_library_opener_parameters%5Bfield_name%5D=field_background_image_desktop&media_library_opener_parameters%5Bentity_id%5D=317&media_library_opener_parameters%5Brevision_id%5D=679&hash=DFIR0-jxQRzOJNa-rFxonuXharUm4T4YWuXkREH-rs0&views_display_id=widget StatusText: error ResponseText: {"message":"Non-reusable blocks must set an access dependency for access control."}
```

I have searched for a solution but still can't figure out how to resolve it. I tried adding a `hook_entity_access()` in my THEME.theme file but that didn't work.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_type_access().
 */
function theme_entity_access($operation, $entity_type_id, $entity, $account) {

  
  if ($entity_type_id === 'block_content' && $operation === 'update') {

    // Allow access to cloned blocks even if permissions missing. 
    return AccessResult::allowed()->cachePerPermissions(); 
  }

}
```

Does anyone know how this can be resolved? Thanks in advance.